# Linear acceleration used for artificial gravity.

Tags: artificial-gravity

If we could actually get to the point where technology allows us to accelerate to 1 g for more than a few minutes, would that acceleration still need to be constant? Since a spaceship can't slow down in space because of the laws of motion, always going on until another force stopped it, wouldn't the people on board feel a constant 1g if say....the thrust was stopped and just left to drift? Or would the artificial gravity from the forces of linear acceleration stop until someone started up the thrust again?

Comment: g is an acceleration. The craft would have to _accelerate_ at a constant rate of 1g in order for the occupants to feel gravity. The thrust would need to be continuous. Think of it this way, do you feel constant acceleration when you're in a car? Only when you speed up, slow down, or turn.

Comment: *Would there still be artificial gravity if the thrust stopped, or would it cease until someone started the thrust again?* It would cease. @user19543 the excellent answers to the linked question in NathanTuggy's comment should help explain it. Your question being marked as a duplicate is not a bad thing, don't worry. This is normal procedure to steer people to well written answers that exist already. [Take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour), ask another, and enjoy SXSE!